# Do these phrases have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning

Do the phrases 'within one week of the date of the request', and 'within one week after the date of the request' (i.e. the request is made 27th October, 28th Oct - 3rd Nov is the one week period after the date of the request) have the same meaning?

Comment: As always, there would be the niggling details of whether the clock starts on the date of the request or the day after, and whether it stops after exactly 7 * 24 hours or carries over to the next day.  And what about the DST/standard time transition?  It's very difficult to get these things to not somehow be ambiguous, especially if someone is determined to "stretch" things somehow.

Comment: (I believe there are about a dozen prior questions on this topic.)

Comment: "within one week of the date of the request" could mean one week before the request.